# I'm having a problem running bcrypt on AWS Lambda NodeJS, Can someone help me?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bcrypt

This is the error shown while running.

On bcrypt's GitHub wiki, they say that it is a native module for node-js and that it requires a compiler and build dependencies in order to build.
What am I doing wrong, can someone please help me

```
{
"errorType": "Error",
"errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header",
"stack": [
    "Error: /var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node: invalid ELF header",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
    "    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)",
    "    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js6️⃣16)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)"
]
```

}

Comment: What command exactly generated this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having the same problem,solved it by using `**bcryptjs** (npm i bcryptjs)` instead of bcrypt package.

It appears bcrypt fails on lambda because it uses node-gyp to build and install - not sure though will have to work though it.

Until then, **bcryptjs** works.

Comment: after install use it like this in the code
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');