# Why does npm install not work as expected when using AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, npm, amazon-ec2

*I'm deploying my node app using AWS. Everything works as expected via manual deployment but things become super weird during automated deployment.*

The manual way ✅

1. I SSH into my EC2 instance and git clone my repo using `git clone git@github.com:USERNAME/REPO.git`
2. I CD into my project and `npm install`
3. `added 2278 packages, and audited 2279 packages in 34s`

**Things work great.**

The automated way, via AWS CodePipeline & CodeDeploy ❌

1. I push new code to my master branch which triggers AWS CodePipeline/CodeDeploy
2. My appspec.yml's install dependencies script provides a log of npm install from `sudo npm install > npm_install.log 2>&1`
3. `added 1991 packages from 970 contributors and audited 1994 packages in 61.326s`

**Why on earth are a different number of packages being installed?**

Things I've checked:

1. I checked the precise SourceArtifact and confirmed that the package.json and package-lock.json in the deployments are identical to what I have locally and what's on my remote master branch.
2. After the Install event on CodeDeploy, I wiped the project directory and decided to run the following command to use a personal access token ("PAT"): `git clone https://asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf@github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git`
3. When using the PAT method, I'm still seeing the 1991 packages figure and not the correct 2278.

**What's going on here?**

One more anomaly I noticed. For some reason, in the automated deployment, I see the following plug that I don't see when I run npm install locally:

```
Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting core-js:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://patreon.com/zloirock 
> https://boosty.to/zloirock 
> bitcoin: bc1qlea7544qtsmj2rayg0lthvza9fau63ux0fstcz 

I highly recommend reading this: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2023-02-14-so-whats-next.md
```

It almost feels like a different variation of `npm install` is running but that seems hard to believe given that I'm running the exact same commands, verbatim. But hopefully this context helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because application dependencies (Node Modules) are OS-specific. For example if you have a library (EG. the most notorious [bcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68918946/im-having-a-problem-running-bcrypt-on-aws-lambda-nodejs-can-someone-help-me)) that works on your MAC during development, you could get a MAC-specific version of it and it is not going to be compatible with Linux, ARM and Windows.

This phenomenon happens because these libraries have their own set of dependencies underneath, thus resulting to different dependency count on different platforms.

This dependency hell is one of the major problems that container / virtualization tools like Docker solves as they allow you to have repeatable and reliable runtimes regardless of the underlying hosts.

Another good practice that one could adapt to reduce the impact of dependency deltas is to use libraries that are not tied up to the underlying operating system. EG. Instead of using `bcrypt` module, use `bcrypt-js` as the later is compatible with more operating systems.

**UPDATE**
@MattGeorge, Assuming we truly have two identical operating systems with `node_modules` downloaded on different points in time. This is usually a result of updates made between the two different points in time on those dependencies. These libraries publish their own sets of updates on their own timing explaining delta between different install points. (PS: Even our operating system-level packages do have updates on their own packages).

**Regarding Upsides/Downsides of using MAC as a server:**

Upsides:

- You can now compile iOS compatible mobile apps
- Powerful and reliable machines
- Access to developer tools and visual interfaces

Downsides:

- Binary mismatch with actual hosting environments of cloud-based components (Linux is the king)
- Cost of running the underlying hardware is much more expensive
- Fewer installation guides for CI/CD tooling

Comment: When I perform an npm install from my EC2 instance via SSH, that should functionally be the same as it being done via my script. How can that be explained?

As a side bar, are there any downsides to running a server on MacOS instead of Linux?

Comment: @MattGeorge just updated the answer bro, if you find the answer helpful, you can click +1 and mark it an answer if it does answer the question. This could help people with the same questions in the future.